# Reflection from/in/off/on a mirror/lake/...?

Tags: prepositions

In scientific fields it is usually "reflection from a mirror". In [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reflection) it is used as in "reflection in the mirror" or "reflection ... on the lake". What sense is conveyed by each usage? My guess is that "reflection from" is used to talk about the light that comes back, "reflection in" is used to talk about the image behind the mirror, and "reflection on" is as if we talk about an image painted on a surface.